# How to produce records that don't meet count criteria with a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to produce the results of a pool match. I am counting the number of frames that a player has won in a match however am having difficulty producing results for those that have not won a frame.

I have read that when using a count and a group by records that return 0 are removed but am unsure on any other methods that I could use.

Please can you advise how I can improve my query below, Thank you :)

```
select 
    t1.Match_ID,
    t1.Home_Player_ID,
    Frames_Won,
    coalesce(Frames_Lost,0) as Frames_Lost
from 
    (
    select 
        Match_ID,
        Home_Player_ID, 
        count(*) as Frames_Won 
    from 
        Match 
    where 
        Home_Player_Win = 1 
    and 
        Match_ID = '56D4FF05-5F33-43FC-A566-2251E790C57F' 
    group by 
        Match_ID,
        Home_Player_ID
    ) t1
left join
    (
    select 
        Match_ID,
        Home_Player_ID, 
        count(*) as Frames_Lost 
    from 
        Match 
    where 
        Home_Player_Win = 0 
    and 
        Match_ID = '56D4FF05-5F33-43FC-A566-2251E790C57F' 
    group by 
        Match_ID,
        Home_Player_ID
    ) t2
on t1.Home_Player_ID = t2.Home_Player_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing records where users have not won any games because of the first subquery limits where home_player_win = 1.

Is there any reason why this query won't work?

```
SELECT
Match_ID,
Home_Player_ID,
SUM(home_player_win)
FROM match
WHERE Match_ID = '56D4FF05-5F33-43FC-A566-2251E790C57F' 
GROUP BY Match_ID, Home_Player_ID;
```

Comment: Sum, of course! The result set returned is exactly what I am after. Thank you.